# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jCarouselLite' Getting this error on implementing jcrousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousellite

I tried restoring all options of slider of jcrousel. It result in error that function jcrousellite not found.

I was working on http://stepgndec.in

Error not yet resolved.

Comment: `jCarouselLite` is its own plugin, it's not part of `jCarousel`.

Comment: but some conflict is there either thier is javascript conflict or some another plugin does not allow slider to work as such.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/142802) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 versions of jQuery loaded on that page. The jCarouselLite plugin is attached to the first instance of jQuery that loaded. Currently, you are getting a reference to the second jQuery that was loaded via the `.noConflict()` call...

```
var $jx = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$jx(function() {
    $jx(".mygallery").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
```

Change it to use the original jQuery object and you should be good...

```
var $jx = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$(function() {
    $(".mygallery").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
```